# errors when drawing a rectangle that is read from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, graphics, jframe, jcomponent

I am new to this website so please forgive me if I have broken any rules. Iv'e been looking for a couple days and have not found an answer to this, please let me know if this has been answered before.

I am creating a java program that can draw an image, (a rectangle in this instance), based on data inside of a file. I have come across an error that I am unable to fix or find a solution for.

this is the main class file where I run everything.

```
package pkg9_weeks_project;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Map {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(640, 640);
        window.setTitle("this is a frame of J's, otherwise known as a JFrame");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

        drawningcomponent DC = new drawningcomponent();
        window.add(DC);
        drawningcomponent.readinmapdata(); //this is to make sure it is reading the file in
    }
}
```

this is the file that reads in and adds the datafile's data into the ArrayList 
and... well.. tries to draw the rectangle with the data inside of the ArrayList

```
package pkg9_weeks_project;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class drawningcomponent extends JComponent
{
    public static ArrayList<String> maptiles2 ; 

    public static void readinmapdata() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        maptiles2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("./src/MapData"));
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            String data[] = line.split("");
            String tile1 = data[0].trim();
            String tile2 = data[1].trim();
            String tile3 = data[2].trim();
            String tile4 = data[3].trim();
            maptiles2.add(tile1);
            maptiles2.add(tile2);
            maptiles2.add(tile3);
            maptiles2.add(tile4);
(This was a test to make sure the items were added
and could be printed from the ArrayList)
            System.out.println(maptiles2.get(0));
            System.out.println(maptiles2.get(1));
            System.out.println(maptiles2.get(2));
            System.out.println(maptiles2.get(3));
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS READING IN FILE");
    }
(This is where the program is coming up with an error)
(I tested the graphics to make sure you could draw a )
(rectangle beforehand and it worked perfectly)
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(5,5,100,200);
            if(maptiles2.get(1).contains("X"))
            {
                g2.draw(rect1);
            }
            if(maptiles2.get(1).contains("O"))
            {
                g2.draw(rect1);
            }

    }
}
```

And last but not least, this is the file I am trying to read in(The file is called MapData)

```
XOXX
```

When I run the class Map, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
X
O
X
X
Success Reading in File
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at pkg9_weeks_project.drawningcomponent.paintComponent(drawningcomponent.java:60)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5230)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:    1572)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1039)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:835)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:7    5)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:7    5)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201    )
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105    )
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I may be wrong but, I have a feeling when it says:
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
it means there are no longer any items in the arraylist maptiles2, but I have no idea at this point and am very confused. For all who respond, thank you for the replies, they are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thank you all for answering, the answer was a simple mistake involving running the method readinmapdata after everything else ran. thank you 
@amit farag and @svarog for your helpful answers!

Comment: It is the end of my first year in Computer Science, so I may not fully understand what you are explaining. So if it is not too much to ask for, please go a bit in depth on your answer. Thanks!

Comment: java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653), you get an IndexArrayOutOfBounds exception because you attempt to reach a segment in memory you haven't yet initialized

Comment: As I said I am a beginner, when you said: "haven't yet initialized", you mean I need to initialize the arraylist, correct?

Comment: the error happens on line 60. it would help if you told us which line that was

Comment: I am sorry! i meant to add that in, the code is in drawningcompunent: if(maptiles2.get(1).contains("X"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be not correct but have you called to the `readinmapdata()` before you called `repaint()`?
it might cause this problem

Comment: Thank you! This solved my errors, oh my this was a simple mistake! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: no problem ;) you will see in the future that it will happen a lot, be careful and always pay attention

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
```

means you are attempting to access the first element in list which has no elements inside, use the add() method to add values to your ArrayList

Comment: I added in the elements I wanted in the method readinmapdata, aparently it does not add it for other methods to use, how would I add the data in so it is there for other methods to use?

Comment: I dont know, as I said I am a slight beginner. is statis not needed or not supposed to be here?

Comment: remove the static keyword and make sure the method runs before the "paintComponent" method, if it doesn't work, test it my moving some values to that method

Comment: Thanks you and @amit farag solved my error. It was caused by a simple mistake of running the readinmapdata method last.